# Why deterministic build behavior differs based on project type

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, csproj, deterministic

I have 2 projects - ClassLibrary1, ClassLibrary2, both with deterministic build enabled. ClassLibrary1 is referencing the ClassLibrary2. If a change is made to ClassLibrary2 and this change does not influence the ClassLibrary1 in any way (e.g. added field, assembly version not changed) then I would expect the deterministic output of ClassLibrary1 doesn't have to change. And in fact, it isn't changed if the projects are the classic non-SDK type. However, once I change the project type to SDK style, any change to ClassLibrary2 causes a binary change of the ClassLibrary1. (tested on net472)

Actually, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/code-generation) states that *The binary contents of all files explicitly passed to the compiler affect determinism.* So I guess the new behavior is rather correct. But I have a few questions.

Why the behavior differs based on project type?

Is it really necessary the deterministic output depends on binary output of referenced libraries (instead of just the API used from them)?

Is there a way how to overcome this and return to original behavior?

Comment: Things are moving like that because they are new. Deterministic compilation is desired, because in many cases (open source NuGet packages for instance) you really want the same code base to always generate the same output in binary.

Comment: @mirva can you try the same setup with SDK style projects and .NET 5 or .NET 6 as a target? This defaults to compilation using reference assembly compilation which should be what you describe. You can opt into the same behavior by setting the property `ProduceReferenceAssembly` to `True` in a csproj property group

Comment: Thanks @martin-ullrich. This really works for whole API surface of the referenced assembly. But it's still not the same behavior as was for the old projects - there only *used* API influenced the output. And btw. producing reference assemblies seems now to be default in .NET5.

Comment: Do you have a reprodible sample? (another thing I can think of that causes this is assembly / file version attributes containing wildcards)